# How to make jsc works with "let" identifier

Tags: javascript, macos, ecmascript-6, command-line-interface

Having **app.js** :

```
  let result=a+b;
```

Using Command line interface `jsc` to run this file:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc app.js
```

And i got this error :

```
Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'result'
```

When i replace `let` by `var` , it works fine .

### How to make jsc works with `let` identifier ?

It is  expected to say  "JSC is in old version"
I don't thing it so , because my mac is :
[image]

Comment: The newest stable version of JavaScriptCore is the first to support `let`, sounds like you have an older version?

Comment: how to upgrade `jsc`

Comment: @loganfsmyth : it works with OOP syntax of ES6 .

Comment: I'm just looking at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/. Safari 9 supported most of classes but not `let`, so that's probably what you're on.